# Editing app.json properties do not effect my react native app (expo)

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am using expo to develop my react native app.
App is working well and I am trying to change `app.json` propeties so that navigation bar will change.
I have added this code to script:

```
"androidNavigationBar": {
  "visible": "sticky-immersive",
  "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF00"
}
```

If I run this with Expo go `expo start --clear` it works as expected on my android device.

When I build the app using `expo run:android -d` or `build -p android --profile preview` (profile is set to buildType apk) or any other build combination as **standalone** app:

Changes are not applied and output is some kind of cached options from old builds or run (i.e. backgroundColor of navigation bar is `#ffff00` from old configurations).

Reseting all caches didn't do the trick.

Got no answers from `expo-navigation-bar` documentaion or git repo.

**What is the correct way to apply changes widely on any production mode?**

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh the emulator by typing R twice in the terminal, or click the emulator and just press R from the keyboard twice. This worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).